# How to add hover rule to css className in order to color specific row on hover in react-table?

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, html-table, react-table

I have successfully applied classname and added color to specific row in my react-table. But I cannot add hover rule to this className to apply another color when I hover over the row. How to apply hover rule to add hover effect? Thanks in advance!

Here is my code:

```
<ReactTable>
...

getTrProps={(state, rowInfo, column, instance) => {

        let className = '';
        if(rowInfo && rowInfo.original){
          if(highlightedCerts.includes(rowInfo.original.id)){
            className = ' highlightedCertRow';
          }
          else if(rowInfo.original.isRevoked) {
            className = ' revokedCertRow';
          }
          else if(rowInfo.original.blocked) {
            className = ' blockedCertRow';
          }
        }
     return {
      ...
     className: className,
     ...
     };
/>
```

Comment: can you provide working example?

Answer (score 0):

Replace `green` color with its rgb code, if `green` code is `0,127,252`, then use `.highlightedCertRow:hover { background-color: rgba(0,127,252, 0.3) !important; }`.

Comment: Thanks. I have solved it on my own. There was a liitle  mistake with nesting tags in css. It made me laugh

Answer (score 0):

I have solved it on my own. There was a little mistake with nesting tags in css.